# Static Reference to Variables in Identical Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, static

I have an activity that consists mainly of a viewpager. The user can open new versions of that activity with different intents, thus making the data in the viewpagers different. Problem is when I access static variables in other classes from the main activity type, it seems as if it is editing variable values in all open versions of the activity. If I finish() the top activity,the data in the original activity has changed to that of the child activity. What is a way to keep references to static variables with only the current activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a way to keep references to static variables with only the current activity?

Quite simply - you can't.

In Java when you declare a variable as `static` in the main body of the class, it is a 'class variable'. This means that all instances of that class share only one variable between them. Consequentially (as you've already found out) changing the value in any instance of the class will change the value for all instances as there is only one 'copy' of the variable.

A golden rule in Android is to *NEVER* use `static` variables or methods in Activities.

There are two reasons for this - if your `Activity` is only ever extended within your ouwn code, then having a `static` variable or method is pointless and (as you've discovered), it's counter-productive.

The second reason is that `static` is often used with the `public` modifier in order to allow an 'all-areas' access to variables and/or methods regardless of whether an actual instance of any given class exists or not - in the case of the class being an `Activity`, this is a *VERY* dangerous game to play because of the life-cycle of Activities.

If you have a 'base' `Activity` which you want to start various instances of but want a common variable they all need to have access to, then simply declare it as...

```
protected Object myVariable;
```

...replacing `Object` with whatever type of variable you want.

Each `Activity` will get there own instance of `myVariable` and can change its value without affecting any other instance of the same `Activity` class.

See the following for [Java Class Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you! I see now why that is a really bad way to do things, and I will change my code. Does protected allow me to access the variables in a static way? If not, how would you access the variables?

Comment: `protected` allows any class which extends your 'base' `Activity` to inherit that variable and use it in any way they need to. It doesn't allow any other class to get access to it externally. This is what I meant about *NOT* declaring variables or methods in an `Activity` as `public` or `public static`. If you want to share data with external classes then either use a 'helper' class or something like `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I will use a helper class then. Thanks!